Hamming Window FPGA Implementation
Like to implement it in FPGA should i just store the Hamming Window coefficients in ROM (so in memory),
And since my input data(that i will feed into hamming window) are sequential ,I will just multiply the current input with the indexed coefficient
Or do we calculate dynamically the coefficients since there is cosine use Cordic algorithm.

Unless you need a variable-length Hamming Window, you simply should store it in ROM. It is much simpler. You could use a simple C program or Matlab script to create the initialization file for your ROM.
Even if you needed a variable-length Hamming window where the upper length is bound to say 256, it would probably be more efficient to store multiple windows in a ROM instead of computing them on-the-fly.

If the multiple lengths are all integer dividers of the longest length, you can simply just store the longest and go just use stride larger than 1 to go through the table.

@Hilmar Good point

Using some technology (FPGA may or may not be among them), exploiting the symmetry of the window to store 1/2 as much in memory (doing a back-and-forth traversal for looking up coeffs) might be worth it.
Something ala (using MATLABs hamming implementation for reference):
N = 4;
a0 = 0.54;
n = 0:N;
w_ref = a0 - (1 - a0)*cos(2*pi*n/N);%hamming(N+1)';

w = a0 - (1 - a0)*cos(2*pi*(0:N/2)/N);
w = [w, w(end-(~rem(N,2)):-1:1)];
assert(all(abs(w - w_ref) < 1e-15))

The cryptic indexing of the mirroring part is to make it work for both even and odd N
wikipedia mentions a0 of 0.54, 25/46 and 0.53836.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function#Examples_of_window_functions
